# Suppressing automatic query used by SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Does anyone know if there is a way of suppressing this query below in the latest version of SSMS.

It is used to populate the database explorer tree in SSMS and starts automatically

Normally this is not an issue however, we have a fair few tables and every refresh the user using SSMS takes 10 seconds and 37M reads on and 155MB of memory on the Database.

we have 300 schemas and 25000 tables.

If we could stop or set up SSMS to not do this it would be better for the servers.

Or does a flag exists to suppress these queries?

```
SELECT
SCHEMA_NAME(sp.schema_id) AS [Schema],
sp.name AS [Name],
sp.object_id AS [ID],
CAST(
case 
    when sp.is_ms_shipped = 1 then 1
    when (
        select 
            major_id 
        from 
            sys.extended_properties 
        where 
            major_id = sp.object_id and 
            minor_id = 0 and 
            class = 1 and 
            name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support') 
        is not null then 1
    else 0
end          
             AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject],
CASE WHEN sp.type = N'P' THEN 1 WHEN sp.type = N'PC' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS [ImplementationType],
CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(smsp.definition, ssmsp.definition) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsEncrypted]
FROM
sys.all_objects AS sp
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smsp ON smsp.object_id = sp.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.system_sql_modules AS ssmsp ON ssmsp.object_id = sp.object_id
WHERE
(sp.type = @_msparam_0 OR sp.type = @_msparam_1 OR sp.type=@_msparam_2)
ORDER BY
[Schema] ASC,[Name] ASC
```

Comment: Have you checked the *startup* setting under Settings > General?

Comment: "we have 300 schemas and 250000 tables."?!?!?

Comment: Yes the startup option of "open empty environment " still generate script

Comment: Yes David each schema in customer populated is a copy of the master schema we also have 10 different databases with each having 300-350 schemas. Inherited not by choice

Comment: What is the performance when connecting as a user who only has access to one schema?  If it's significantly better, then you could adopt a Just-In-Time schema-level access for SSMS users.  Long term Database-per-Customer is a better model, or at least fewer Schemas per Database.

Comment: Separate PaaS db is in future road map,  I will check out  Just-In-Time schema-level access thanks